# How can I specify the version of Gradle Kotlin plugin in subproject that different from the root one

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, jetbrains-compose

I'm working on a multiproject, the Kotlin plugin version in `./build.gradle.kts` is 1.7.0, but as I'm using compose-jb in the subproject, it requires 1.6.X because it throws exceptions on 1.7.0. And there is no other compose-jb version supporting 1.7.0 according to [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/issues/2108#issuecomment-1152613072).

So I wonder if I can specify the version of the Kotlin plugin of the subproject, or is there a another way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to mix multiple Kotlin versions in an multiplatform project. Pick the latest version that is supported by all your dependencies to avoid further complications.

Newer versions of [Compose Multiplatform](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform) are released with support for Kotlin 1.8.0 (and probably newer). The project is constantly updated to support the latest versions.

Each submodule in a multiplatform project has it's own `build.gradle.kts` where you can specify the version of dependencies and plugins, but it is very error-prone (and very likely not what you want) to mix multiple versions of the same plugin / dependency in the same project.